# Multi-threading with bash

Tags: multithreading, bash, ssh

It may look menacing, but the task is really simple:

server has the following directory structure:

```
/usr/multi
    /1
        job
        file.a
        file.b
    /2
        job
        file.a
        file.b
    /3
        job
        file.a
        file.b
```

And the following code:

```
#this is thread.sh
cd /usr/multi
#find the first directory that has a job file    
id=$(ls */job)
#strip everything after "/" ("1/job" becomes "1")
id=${id%%/*}
#read job
read job <$id/job
if [ "$id" == "" ] || [ "$job" == "" ]
then
    false
else
    #mark that id as busy
    mv $id/job $id/_job
    #execute the job
    script.sh $1 $job
    #mark that id as available
    mv $id/_job $id/job
fi
```

`script.sh` performs some operations (described in `job` file and received argument) on `file.a` and `file.b`.

Clients, on the other hand, execute this code:

```
#loop infinitely on failure, break loop on success
false
while [ "$?" != "0" ]
do
    result=$(ssh $server "thread.sh 'some instructions'" </dev/null)
done
echo $result
```

So every client gets a separate `id` and gives the server `some instructions` to perform the `job` specified for that `id`. If there are more clients than available jobs on the server, clients will keep trying to grab the first available `id` and when they do, give `some instructions` to the server to perform corresponding `job`.

The problem is that every once in a while two clients get the same `id`; and `thread.sh` messes up the `file.a` and `file.b`.

My theory is that this happens when two clients request an `id` from the server at almost the same time, so that server cannot rename the `job` file quick enough for one client to see it as available, and the other one to see it as busy.

Should I put random sleep interval just before the `if [ "$id" == "" ] || [ "$job" == "" ]` so I will get some more randomness in the timing?

Comment: maybe it's better to lock the `job` file . take a look at `flock`'s manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly determined, your script is quite [racy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

A simple locking in bash can be implemented using

```
set -o noclobber
```

and writing to a lockfile. If the lock is already being held (the file exists), your write attempt will fail in an atomic manner.

Comment: So, if I add set -o noclobber to my /etc/profile, I will prevent parallel running cp and mv from doing operations on the same files? Is it as simple as that or am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't do it in `profile`, do it in the script that does the locking. It doesn't affect `cp` or `mv` at all. It **does** affect the behavior of output redirection via `>filename`. See the Bash manual, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output

Comment: what about `mv -n`, for my job file?

Comment: To avoid the Race Condition, you need a locking mechanism. Altering the commands you are using will not help you, as long as your concurrency remains unchecked.